# Get superView frame in lazy var? (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I have declared `UIImageView` using `lazy var`,

I want to set x position of `redArrowImage` according to it's superView which will be define at run time.

```
lazy var redArrowImage: UIImageView = {
    let imageView = UIImageView(image:  UIImage(named: "red"))
    imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.goButton.frame.size.width - 25, y: 12, width: 15, height: 15)
    imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return imageView
}()
```

I have used  `self.superview.frame.size.width - 25` but it not works :(

```
imageView.frame = CGRect(x: self.superview.frame.size.width - 25, y: 12, width: 15, height: 15)
```

Any idea ?

Comment: If the view didn't load yet, how _can_ `self.superview.frame.size.width` work? Try instead adding such code to `viewDidLoad()`

Comment: @user770 my motto was to make this function generic. & make dry code.

Comment: @Ramesh, the code wont work unless the views on which it depends themselves have valid frames. Did you try using this variable in viewDidAppear ? Did it work ?

Comment: @humblePilgrim we can set the frames later on, yes it will work. My question is can we set something in `lazy var block` ?